# How to remain visible div after mouse out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have view And I want to open a `open-ebooks` div when mouse over on `ebooks_container` this is working fine. But when open mouse over on `open-ebooks` but this is hidden and I want to remain open.

```
<div> <a id="ebooks_container"><%=get_ebook_status %> ebooks is added</a> 
</div>
<div class="open_ebooks">This is test <br> No one can purchase it </div>
```

And js

```
 $('a#ebooks_container').mouseover(
    function () {
      $(".open_ebooks").animate({height: 80},"slow");
      $(".open_ebooks").addClass("open_ebooks_display");
    }
  );   

$('a#ebooks_container').mouseleave(
   function () {
     $(".open_ebooks").removeClass("open_ebooks_display");
     $(".open_ebooks").hide().animate({height:'20px'}, 1000)
   }
 );                 

$(".open_ebooks").mouseover(
  function () {
    $(".open_ebooks").animate({height: 80},"slow");
    $(".open_ebooks").addClass("open_ebooks_display");
  }
);
```

And `CSS`

```
#ebooks_container {
  background-color: activeborder;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.open_ebooks{
  display: none;
  width:100%;
}

.open_ebooks_display{
  display: block !important
}
```

Comment: We even need the CSS to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

try adding .show() like so on your bottom function

```
$(".open_ebooks").show().addClass("open_ebooks_display");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use slideUp and slideDown to show verticle show/hide animation

```
 $('a#ebooks_container').mouseover(
    function () {
      $(".open_ebooks").slideDown("slow");        
      $(".open_ebooks").addClass("open_ebooks_display");
    }
  ); 

 $('a#ebooks_container').mouseleave(function () {
     $(".open_ebooks").removeClass("open_ebooks_display");
     $(".open_ebooks").slideUp("slow");
    });
```